# Swift : Upload pdf as "admin user" and send notification to other "normal users" that pdf is uploaded

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, nsnotifications

I'm a swift beginner.
I'm trying to create an app that essentially does the following :

Users can sign up and login to the app to receive a new recipe weekly in a pdf (or word doc) format. Once the new recipe of the week is ready to be viewed the users will receive a notification that "recipe of the week is ready for viewing" and they can then login and access the new recipe (as well as recipes from previous weeks).

One admin user will be able to login and upload these pdfs/word doc that contain the recipe and once the upload is complete, the other normal users are notified of this new recipe.

My question :
1) Is it possible to have different users in one app? (ie normal users and admin users). I just want to make the app easy to use for the admin (a friend who is not a tech and who just want to upload recipes) without having to touch the codes or needing me to upload them manually. If its not possible, what could be an alternative way of doing this, so that an ordinary admin user can just upload into the app for other users viewing pleasure?

2) I just thought pdf/word doc might be an easier way for the friend to upload the recipes into app (the recipe might contain pics, tables, graphs etc), if there is a different way of doing this, open to suggestions :) At first I thought maybe putting the recipes on a shared directory and getting Apple's DirectoryMonitor.swift to monitor the directory so that everytime the friend uploads something to the directory, the app will detect this and send notifications to other users....but I thought maybe this isnt the best way to do it, not to mention it might send false notifications (ie when files are removed insteaf of added..)

I do know the basics of Swift, or think I do.So hopefully if you can provide me enough hints (ie framework or SDK  or classes to use etc etc) I can use your suggestions to do further research on the subject.

If you need more details or clarifications, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You know the basics of Swift, but do you know how a networking app should work? Maybe you can learn how to use `Firebase` and format the data in `JSON` first, pdf/word doc is not suitable for using as data for the app

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am currently researching Firebase and how to use it. Dumb Newbie Question : why is a pdf/word doc not suitable for an app? If I use Firebase to enable my admin user to login, is it not a good idea for her to be able to upload a pdf (with images and text in it) to Firebase Storage and enable other normal users to see that document using the app? (I dont know whether this is possible yet, still reading up on Firebase, just speculating).

Comment: Also, as I understand it, JSON is text-based, so admin wont be able to share info containing images and texts in it?

Comment: The images is never a matter, you can either upload it to image hosting service and get the image URL, then it become a text, or encode it to base64 to store also as text, using JSON is best practice for app because its light weight, many library support, and easy read/parse/create and show as native UI. Firebase free storage is not so large, if you store the whole pdf/doc it will become unnesscessary in the future, store text-only JSON is more prefered

Comment: Showing the whole pdf/doc in phone is also mean the performance would go down a lot, not to mention the screen size and stuff that will make the user have to zoom out to read, is never a good pratice

Answer (score 0):

You must use web services (server) to achieve this stuff.

Design api for login like if admin user login then you return something like this is admin and shows admin screens in your app like upload dishes etc.

If normal user will login then your api (web service) will return you that this is a normal user then show stuff regarding it in your app.

You required web services for uploading and retrieving recipes.

You can easily manage notification if admin upload new recipe to server.

So, it's basically depends on your server and mobile both side of proper management. Your database will take place server side. that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Lion! I'm reading up on Firebase to try to understand how to use to achieve my app's goal.....however I'm struggling to find any example on uploading a document (eg pdf with text and pics in it) using the app integrated with Firebase. There are some examples to upload images, but not other types of docs...any thoughts?